# Citing articles as references for the Leave-One-Out Method

Tags: cross-validation, references

I wish to know which work(s) should be cited as reference(s) for the Leave-One-Out method.

Comment: You mean leave one out cross validation?

Comment: @MatthewDrury , Yes.

Comment: The Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman is a well known and standard reference.  It covers many aspects of the cross validation method, including leave one out, in detail in chapter 7.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, why not make that an official answer? Otherwise, this thread will be counted as unanswered.

Comment: @gung Sure, will do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman is a well known and standard reference. It covers many aspects of the cross validation method, including leave one out, in detail, in chapter 7.